# MASM0001: Default configuration file jaxws-tubes-default.xml was not found

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws

I am seeing this error repeatedly in my GlassFish 4.1 server logs for my domain:

```
MASM0001: Default configuration file [jaxws-tubes-default.xml] was not found
```

What is this `jaxws-tubes-default.xml` and where do I need to place it to clear this SEVERE log entry? It is repeated approximately 20-25 times periodically.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't happen in a default installation, I guess you are doing something JAX-WS/Metro specific? Then this error may be the result of a missing `metro.xml`.

The file `jaxws-tubes-default.xml` seems to hold the default configuration for JAX-WS [tubes](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube.html).

I don't where exactly this comes from but you can try to fix it by placing the `jaxws-tubes-default.xml` in the `META-INF` directory of your application with the following content:

```
<metro xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/metro/config' version="1.0">
    <tubelines default="#default-metro-tubeline">
        <tubeline name="default-metro-tubeline">
            <client-side>
                <!--<tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.TerminalTubeFactory" />-->
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.ValidationTubeFactory" />
                <!--<tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.MonitoringTubeFactory" />-->
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.MustUnderstandTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.AddressingTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.dump.MessageDumpingTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.BasicTransportTubeFactory" />
            </client-side>
            <endpoint-side>
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.dump.MessageDumpingTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.AddressingTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.MustUnderstandTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.MonitoringTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.ValidationTubeFactory" />
                <tube-factory className="com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.TerminalTubeFactory" />
            </endpoint-side>
        </tubeline>
    </tubelines>
</metro>
```

(Taken from the [Java.net Metro Repository](https://java.net/projects/jax-ws/sources/sources/content/branches/jaxws22/jaxws-ri/rt/etc/jaxws-tubes-default.xml?rev=13209))

[This page](https://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#dynamic_tube-based_message_logging) from the Metro Documentation contains a similar example.

Comment: I put it in every META-INF directory I could find and it had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem with Web-Logic server while starting deployed Web-service. The solution provided in [www.databaseusers.com/article/6408029](https://www.databaseusers.com/article/6408029/Upgrading+to+WLS+12.1.3+only+to+hit+metro-default.xml+not+found+issue) and [www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6PEW_10.0.0/com.ibm.help.omtroubleshoot.doc/troubleshooting/ts_DeployEARbuiltwihJAXWSwebservice.html) helped to solve the issue.

I had to add "metro-default.xml" file in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF as mentioned in [www.databaseusers.com/article/6408029](https://www.databaseusers.com/article/6408029/Upgrading+to+WLS+12.1.3+only+to+hit+metro-default.xml+not+found+issue) into WAR file.

If "META-INF" folder is not already present at above location we need create one with "metro-default.xml".

The content of "metro-default.xml" can be found here [www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6PEW_10.0.0/com.ibm.help.omtroubleshoot.doc/troubleshooting/ts_DeployEARbuiltwihJAXWSwebservice.html).

Hope this will help.